# react-google-charts not displaying on ie11 - 'Cannot draw chart data'

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, google-visualization

I am using react v16.5 and react-google-charts v3.0.8

I understand ie11 doesnt support svg transitions, the charts are not animated and yet they will not load on ie11. In place of every chart I get the error 'Cannot draw chart: no data specified'. Working fine on all other browsers

Comment: will you please share the code?

Comment: Also check the console to see if there is any other error or warning message may help to narrow down the issue. You can also try to post the working example can help us to understand the issue in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-google-charts v3.0.8 uses the includes-method on arrays, which isn't supported by IE11.
Use a polyfill for this. See: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2856